# RSpec/Capybara test failing with no method error for model setter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara, rspec-rails

**Short Version**

I have added a company model to my rails app which is in the devise user registration view using accepts_nested_attributes on the user model. The setup works when I run through it manually but when I execute the test it fails with:

```
Failure/Error: click_button 'Sign up'
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `owner_id=' for #<Company:0x007fe2411e17b8>
```

How can I fix this error? I am not sure what it is telling me.

The test code which is in spec/features:

**authentication_flows_spec.rb**

```
it "signs me up" do
  visit new_user_registration_path
  fill_in 'user[email]', with: @new_user[:email]
  fill_in 'user[password]', with: @new_user[:password]
  fill_in 'user[password_confirmation]', with: @new_user[:password]
  fill_in 'user[company_attributes][name]', with: @new_user[:company_name]
  click_button 'Sign up'
  expect(current_path).to eq(dashboard_path)
end
```

**Long Version**

Recently I have added a Company model to my app which has two relationships. One to say it *has_many* users and one to say it *belongs_to* an owner (which is a existing user).

**Company Model**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_many :users
end
```

The company is created in the devise user registration by telling my user model to *accepts_nested_attributes_for* the company.

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
end
```

**Devise User Registration View**

```
.section.first.dark-grey.p-b-20
  .container
    .grid
      .col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
        %h2.grid-title Sign up
        = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
          = devise_error_messages!
          .form-row
            = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", placeholder: "email address"
          .form-row
            = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control", placeholder: "password"
          .form-row
            = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control", placeholder: "confirm password"
          = f.fields_for :company_attributes do |ff|
            .form-row
              = ff.text_field :name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "company name"
          .form-row
            = f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary btn-cons"
        = render "devise/shared/links"
```

Finally I override the devise user registrations controller to add the logic to set the owner of the company

**Overriden Devise Registrations Controller**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

    #GET /users/sign_up
    def new
      # Override Devise default behaviour and create a company as well
      build_resource({})
      resource.build_company
      respond_with self.resource
    end

    #POST /users/sign_up
    def create
      # Let devise create user and company using nested attributes
      super 
      # Set the owner of the newly created company as new user
      company = resource.company
      company.owner_id = resource.id
      company_saved = company.save
      if company_saved == false
        resource.destroy
        company.destroy
        return new_user_registration_path
      end  
    end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
        u.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :company_attributes => :name)
      }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your [Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/2cos9t/unusual_rspeccapybara_test_failure_i_thought_it/), adding `attr_accessor :owner_id` seemed to resolve the problem.  That suggests that the test db schema really is the problem as @HermanHiddema suggests.  Instead of db:test:prepare (removed in 4.1), you could do `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load` or similar to drop the existing schema and recreate from scratch.

maintain_test_schema! appears to only load the schema if you the schema version is different from the one in the DB.  So if you modified migrations that had already run (as one example), it wouldn't detect that the test schema needs to be reset.

Comment: Hey thanks - I had a go at this last night again before you posted and turns out you are correct :) It is down to a bug in rails (rolling back a migration changing and then applying isn't reflected in test DB. https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/15787) rake db:test:clone fixed it. I will put a more complete write up on Reddit later.

Answer (score 2):

Have you run rake db:test:prepare? If your test database does not have an owner_id column on the companies table yet, you could get an error like this.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me as I am using Rails 4 so the test DB is managed automatically for me. I believe the line: ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema! in the rails_helper.rb of RSpec does this for me as well. (But I have tried it anyway!). But still thanks for reading through it.